# Angular UI: Unknown provider: dialogProvider

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to replicate the following Angular UI example of a simple dialog with a close-button. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dialog/README.md.
However, I cannot get the `dialog` parameter to be injected properly into my dialog controller.

The controllers looks like below (using CoffeScript)

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

angular.module('myApp').controller 'MyController', ($dialog, $scope) ->
  $dialog.dialog().open('dialogTemplate', 'DialogController')

angular.module('myApp').controller 'DialogController', ['$scope', 'dialog', ($scope, dialog) ->
    $scope.close = -> dialog.close()
]
```

See the Plunker for a live version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ejKh7w8Sk9H7Nz3rXhdc?p=preview

Angular gives me the following error:

```
Unknown provider: dialogProvider <- dialog
```

Any ideas on how the `dialog`-parameter could be injected into `DialogController`, as is seen in the docs example referred to above? I suspect this could have something to do with CoffeeScript since I am fairly new to this language, but it seems quite right when I look at the compiled output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was struggling to find a solution.

I was expecting two additional arguments to my controller; `..., selectedView, dialog)`. It seemed to provide my dialog with the right arguments, but I still got an error in the console.

The problem was that I was referencing the controller twice;

1. When opening my dialog: `dialog.open('template', 'myController')`
2. In my `template` file: `section(ng-controller='myController')`

Removing (2) resolved the problem, since that wasn't invoked by the dialog code, which provided my `selectedView` argument and the default `dialog` argument.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: not sure why you got downvoted - this is the correct answer. Reto's answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog provider is named `$dialog` (s. [dialog.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dialog/dialog.js#L14)). So you have to name the injected value `$dialog` like you did correctly in *MyController*.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller 'DialogController', ['$scope', '$dialog', ($scope, $dialog) ->
  $scope.close = -> dialog.close()
]
```

→ [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOe6O983sTc2kPgdW8OH?p=preview)

*Note:* As you define your dependencies as strings the controller arguments can be named as you like:

```
... ['$scope', '$dialog', (myscope, mydialog) -> ...
```

Comment: this is not correct. $dialog is the angular ui injector, dialog is the singleton object of the current dialog. ['$scope', '$dialog', (myscope, mydialog) doesn't make sense either because this construction is used only to avoid minification problems.

see Kristofer's answer for possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Kristofer Sommestad** is right here. but i got the same problem.problem was some older version of `ui-bootstrap-tpls`(like version 0.11.0) does not support `$dialog`.so used new version of `ui-bootstrap-tpls`.